# Networking switch boxes distance from 480v transformers

Tags: switch, power

I am working on a network layout for a manufacturing plant and ran into a situation I am just not experienced in. We have 6 steel beams from the ground to the ceiling that we are planning on mounting switch boxes which will contain a UPS and a Meraki MS120-48P. One of the beams will contain a 480v transformer for some manufacturing equipment which is the same pole I had planned to install a switch box. As of right now, the switch box is going to be 5-6 feet above the transformer. Is this going to cause any interference with the network switch?

Comment: At five to six feet separation, it is unlikely to be a problem. You really need to consult the AHJ (Authority Having Jurisdiction), such as a building inspector or fire marshal The AHJ has the ability to red-tag and close the building until the violation is corrected. Each jurisdiction has its own rules about both high- and low-voltage cabling, and the required separation between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will consult our electrition as a first pass.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure to use S/FTP cable, the more shielding the better, otherwise induced currents are going to be a continuous problem. The problem grows with the size of the transformer, so plan accordingly.
2. Shielded cables need to be properly grounded at both ends, aka. to mains ground, not just to the nearest random object made out of metal.
3. Make sure that you can install anything above the transformer, as some have exposed connections on top and only locations below a certain distance from the bottom of a transformer is normally consider safe. Might still be possible to install stuff above it, but you might want to consider if powering down the transformer is possible every time you want to do maintenance on your equipment.
4. If you need to cross a high current conductor with a signal cable (CAT6 for example), do it perpendicular to the high current conductor, and only go parallel again at a safe distance of a couple of feet. This way the induced magnetic field is kept at a minimum.

Answer (score 6):

From an electrical / magnetic aspect, power is 50/60Hz and presents very little noise to ethernet, however induced currents could be a problem. 5-6ft would typically be sufficient, but you'll need to consult professionals for whatever your local code requirements might be. (fire, grounding, HV/LV isolation, etc.)

In "high noise" environments, I've always recommended shielded cabling, and NEMA enclosures -- even inside a building.